# Replacing all the symbols from one array with the complementary symbols in the other one JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

So that's the problem.

I tried to write an algorithm that will process a given `string` and `.replace()` symbols from the first array (I called it `startSyms`) with the complementary symbols from another array (`endSyms`). The logic is obvious. If we'd use `.indexOf()` function, it will return a positive number (position of the symbol that we want to replace) or, if there are no more symbols like this in the string, the output will be -1.

> So you can see how I did it. First I've used `for` loop to go through
>   each of the symbols of the first array `beginSyms` and inside this
>   `for` loop I put the `while` loop so that `.replace()` method will
>   replace `beginSyms[i]` with `endSyms[i]` while the `.indexOf(
>   beginSyms[i] )` is more than `-1`. When it becomes -1 `while` loop
>   suppose to stop and `for` loop suppose to switch to the next symbol of
>   the array.

```
function replacer(string) {
  var beginSyms = ["*","**","^","^^","_|"],
      endSyms = ["<b>","</b>","<i>","</i>","<br>"],
      string = string;

  for ( i = 0; i < (beginSyms.length - 1); i++ ) {
    while ( string.indexOf(beginSyms[i]) > (-1) ) {
      string = string.replace(beginSyms[i], endSyms[i]); // function used to run all the specialised text apparatus
    }
  }

  return string;
}
```

This algorithm seems to be looping forever and, therefore, crashing my browser when I try to run it. Please explain where I went wrong and give a suitable solution for this. I've been searching through the StackOverflow to find the answer and people used `RegExp` there to do this kind of stuff but I don't know what is it and where it came from so if your answer contains something like this, please explain how it works.

Thank you!

P. S. I know that there will be a bug with replacing this `**` as `.indexOf()` and `.replace()` couldn't differentiate `*` and `**` without a special checking but it seems to me that it is not the main problem for now and I can fix it later.

Comment: Can you give the sample text which makes the loop never ending? Since I tried with a text and it works and the loop ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the loop is not ending in your above case which (*while* loop) ends when it can't find the symbol to replace.

But I have noticed, you could do two things as below to make your function works as you expected.

1. Don't declare the variable with the same same as the parameter `var
   string = string` as it won't do anything new which you can remove.
2. Also, reorder your `beginSyms` to put `**` first then `*` to make
   the replace work correctly and also do the same thing with `^^`.

**Sample snippet**:

```js
function replacer(string) {
  var beginSyms = ["**", "*", "^^", "^",  "_|"],
      endSyms = ["</b>", "<b>", "</i>", "<i>", "<br>"];

  for ( i = 0; i < beginSyms.length - 1; i++ ) {
    while (string.indexOf(beginSyms[i]) > -1) {
      string = string.replace(beginSyms[i], endSyms[i]); // function used to run all the specialised text apparatus
    }
  }

  return string;
}

console.log(replacer('Test text with *trial** and ^error^^'));
```